# Using slicing and indexing of PANDAS dataframe to pass as x y co-ordinates to Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, slice

Hi I am having trouble extracting parts of two columns in a PANDAS dataframe, with each column becoming x and y coordinates of a matplotlib plot.

I have some hardware that produces data like this:

```
Some text here

start=0.2300 end=0.6800

Col0      Col1      Col2     Col3      Col4    Col5
0.0000  1.262257 -2.358180  0.659226 -0.148103 -0.396258
0.1100  0.036566 -0.119857  1.305843  0.445102  0.586046
0.2300  1.090691 -0.957441 -1.507930 -0.009555  0.153534
0.3700 -0.582869  0.719073  1.092839  0.933759  0.077195
0.4200 -1.153562  0.950388  0.207947  0.678560  0.299933
0.5400  0.164422 -0.927772  0.642784  1.522672  0.483578
0.6800 1.178238 -2.597361  1.039083 -2.056909  0.117656
0.7500  0.144455  0.758041 -0.322278  0.152447  0.611217
```

What I am trying to do is extract Col0 between the start and end times to pass as the x co-ordinates and extract the same range of Col5 to pass as the y coordinates

I have a regex search to isolate the start and end codes from line 3 stored as 'start' and 'end'.  I can also get the index of the relevant start and end part.

```
loop_start = df[df['Col0'] == start].index.item
loop_end = df[df['Col0] == end].index.item
```

The problems start when I try to slice the dataframe ready to pass to matplotlib. When I try

```
y = df.iloc[loop_start:loop_end, 5].values
x = df.iloc[loop_start:loop_end, 0].values
```

This returns

```
 TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [<bound method Int64Index.item of Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')>] of <class 'method'>
```

I have converted my 'start' and 'end' values to int since they were initially floats and I thought that might have prevented the == statement from working.

Any help at this stage would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're setting your start and end to functions, not values. Simple fix, change your definition of loops_start/end by adding parenthesis to `item`

```
loop_start = df[df['Col0'] == start].index.item()
loop_end = df[df['Col0'] == end].index.item()
y = df1.iloc[loop_start:loop_end, 5].values
x = df1.iloc[loop_start:loop_end, 0].values
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I've marked this as correct since it was the quickest fix for me, but all three worked.  I upvoted everyone but since Im new here it doesn't show (thanks to all though!)

Answer (score 0):

If you set ColO to be the index you can easily grab the subset you are after:

```
start = 0.23
end = 0.68
df = df.set_index('Col0')
df_subset = df[start:end]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just use `.loc` to subset your DataFrame

```
start = 0.23 
end = 0.68
x,y = df.loc[df.Col0.between(start, end), ['Col0', 'Col5']].values.T

x
#array([0.23, 0.37, 0.42, 0.54, 0.68])
y
#array([0.153534, 0.077195, 0.299933, 0.483578, 0.117656])
```